# Girl who can shapeshift and at one point turns into a drop of water

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, shape-shifter

I read this book years ago, and it was about a girl who is taken through a portal I think, she is holding onto her dad's hand but she lets go for a second and gets taken away, and I think she can shapeshift into anything. She is being trained for something but I can't remember, and at one point she shapeshifts into a water droplet. There's other characters too, some kind of queen or a woman in a position of power.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you tell us when "years ago" was?  The more specific you can be the better.  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there are any other details you can [edit] into your question.